# SWT StackLayout topControl apparently not working

Tags: java, layout, swt

I am testing a simple SWT StackLayout example to learn how it works but things are not working as I expected.

I created a StackLayout with two buttons on them, both set to cycle the top control between the two of them five times when they are selected, with a 2-second pause every time the top control changes. However, when I run the problem I do not see anything happen.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StackLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;


public class MyApp {

    protected Shell shlMyFirstSwt;
    Button btnOne;
    Button btnTwo;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MyApp window = new MyApp();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shlMyFirstSwt.open();
        shlMyFirstSwt.layout();
        while (!shlMyFirstSwt.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shlMyFirstSwt = new Shell();
        shlMyFirstSwt.setSize(621, 416);
        shlMyFirstSwt.setText("My First SWT Application");
        StackLayout layout = new StackLayout();
        shlMyFirstSwt.setLayout(layout);

        Button btnOne = new Button(shlMyFirstSwt, SWT.NONE);
        btnOne.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i != 10; i++) {
                    layout.topControl = i % 2 == 0? btnOne : btnTwo;
                    shlMyFirstSwt.layout();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        btnOne.setText("One");

        Button btnTwo = new Button(shlMyFirstSwt, SWT.NONE);
        btnTwo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i != 10; i++) {
                    layout.topControl = i % 2 == 0? btnOne : btnTwo;
                    shlMyFirstSwt.layout();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        btnTwo.setText("Two");
    }
}
```

**Elaborating after first answer:**

Trying a simpler approach without delaying. Now I modified the event handler to simply have one button switch the top control to be the other button, as shown below. I expected the two buttons to alternate as top control, but instead when I click on the first button, the window turns blank. Any idea why?

```
        Button btnOne = new Button(shlMyFirstSwt, SWT.NONE);
        btnOne.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                layout.topControl = btnTwo;
                shlMyFirstSwt.layout();
            }
        });
        btnOne.setText("One");

        Button btnTwo = new Button(shlMyFirstSwt, SWT.NONE);
        btnTwo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                layout.topControl = btnOne;
                shlMyFirstSwt.layout();
            }
        });
        btnTwo.setText("Two");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: just the silly mistake of including btnTwo in the first event handler before it was initialized, even though it is *used* after initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Thread.sleep` calls are blocking the user interface thread so the GUI does not get updated. You must never block the user interface thread like this. Calls to methods like `layout` do not update instantly - they require that `display.readAndDispatch` runs to dispatch the various updates that are generated.

If you want to delay something use `Display.timerExec`:

```java
Display.getDefault().timerExec(2000, new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
     ... code to be run after the delay
   }
});
```

So you will have to rework your code to use this to do the timed updated.

Comment: Thanks, @greg-449. As you may see in the revised question, I am still having issues after removing delaying altogether.

I am still curious about your point, though. Why does Thread.sleep block the user interface thread, if it lasts only 2 seconds and then resumes? Shouldn't everything work as usual after those 2 seconds?

Comment: Ok, I see now that Thread.sleep does not block things completely, they resume after 2 seconds, but the 10 intermediary shlMyFirstSwt.layout(); calls don't do anything because they are all executed before event handler returns. When that happens, the interface is finally updated but the top control is the same as previously, so no changes are observed (had the for loop count to an odd number instead of 10, the controls would indeed alternate). This problem occurs even if Thread.sleep is not present.